# Is "pal" too informal when the other person is much older than me?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, politeness

I have an online friend (here on StackExchange) and I happen to know that he is significantly "more experienced", he's a professor while I'm a student, and his contribution here is larger than mine. Still, we surely consider each other friends, we treat each other equally, make jokes on each other etc. Is it ok to call such a person "pal" in the chat, like:

> Thanks a lot, pal!

Or is this word too impolite in this case? And would there be a good substitute for this situation?

Comment: I suspect that the answer will depend on your friend and on your friendship, and the circumstances of your exchange. Some people always prefer to maintain their distance, and would be uncomfortable being called *pal*, *buddy*, *mate*, *dude*, *bro*, or other terms of familiarity by one who is a friend, but professionally very junior or senior. Others will be uncomfortable if you do *not* use those terms of familiarity when you do with others, especially in informal settings. But I also suspect this question will be deemed off-topic for this site.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I have read the FAQ. The first point of "welcomed" reads: _Word choice and usage_, and one of the "don't ask" mentioned there fits to this question. So it might be off-topic, but not because of the topics listed in the FAQ. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @tohecz: The FAQ isn't crystal clear about everything; it's not unusual for a newcomer to ask a question that seems within boudaries, but the community doesn't view it quite the same way. I think your question is interesting and well-written, so, even if it does get closed, take heart in the helpful responses you are getting.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Yes, I'm glad to see that, I only point out that linking a member to FAQ, when the member has 21k SE rep (so he obviously knows how SE sites work) and the FAQ doesn't provide a help for this question being on-topic or no, it is a bit strange ;)

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked your rep, of course. I'm glad you're here, nonetheless! :-)

Comment: I'm in two minds over this one. It seems to me it's Not Constructive, because *we* can't provide a definitive answer to the question of whether "pal" is okay in his exact context. But perhaps we could agree on an alternative that conveys a sense of friendship without the risk of sounding impertinent/presumptive (not that I can think of anything suitable, to be honest! :)

Comment: FYI, these types of questions will be addressed in Etiquette (if it reaches beta), since this question seems to address politeness, social customs, etc.

Comment: @eazar001 Still, I was not aware of the phrase using as sarcasm, which is definitely a matter of language and not of etiquette. So maybe I didn't explain my problem precisely in the question, but the answer by **rhetorician** is helpful, yet is about English and not about etiquette I think ;)

Comment: @tohecz, I wasn't trying to redirect your question to another hub, I was just literally stating that hub might be of interest to you that's all. I realize that your question overlaps domains, no offense intended.

Comment: @eazar: I wasn't aware of the Etiquette site; thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @J.R. No problem, it hasn't reached beta yet though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I call a certain friend of mine on the phone, I usually say, "Hey, Chuck, this is Don," and he says, "Hey, good buddy!"  To me, his use of the word *good* with *buddy*--not to mention the pleasant tone of his voice-- makes all the difference to me, as it may with your online friend.  I cannot say the same, however, about "good pal," "good bro'," "good mate," or "good dude."  I don't know, they just don't sound right!

By the way, the nonverbal aspects of spoken communication, such as tone of voice, do not "translate" so well in written communication.  This may sound patently obvious, but it's still worth considering when that little voice inside of you gives you pause, and you ask yourself, "Should I use this expression or not?"  It sounds to me as if you might have some doubts about using the expression "Thanks a lot, pal!" with your online friend.  In spoken communication I've heard that locution used in an ironic, even sarcastic, tone too many times for it to sound--to me, anyway--perfectly innocent or friendly in written communication.